# Ideas for notification of asynchronous events

Tags: c++, callback, notifications

I'm developing a system that requires various data to be passed from a very low level library to higher level C++ application. The general flow is the C++ application layer makes a request to the low level library and then the low level library will reply asynchronously with the result. Between the C++ application and the low level library there are many layers. For example, the application may have a method called GetEventDetails which calls a few other classes before the low level library. E.g.

```
App::GetEventDetails
--ClassA::GetEventDetails
---ClassB::GetEventDetails
-----LowLevelLib::GetEventDetails
..
.. at some point in future...
..
LowLevelLib::ReturnEventDetails
```

Now when the low level library returns with the result it does not know about the Application layer to pass the result back. So one method maybe to pass down a pointer to some kind of notification handler all the way from the App class to the low level code but it can add a lot of extra code at every level just to pass this pointer.

I'm wondering how others approach similar problems?

Comment: Why do you need all of these layers?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). If you are not going to use it, at least, by looking at its architecture description, you will get a good idea of what to do and typical issues to deal with. But I would suggest you use it because it is hard to make asynchronous I/O in a way that is really robust, practical and fast, Boost.Asio does it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

notification handler in this scope is the same as any other parameter. just pass it down your layers. review your architecture if you have deep nesting and often need to pass many parameters from the highest to the lowest layers.